# $('body').on('change', '.selector', function() { }); not working as expected for <select> tag jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar

I am new to web development, especially Jquery and Bootstrap. I need to accept date from users on my page, where they have the option to either give only **Year** or **Year & Month** or **Year, Month & Day**. So, instead of using a calendar picker I decided to use 3 `<select>` tags for this.

**My Requirements**

1. Without selecting Year, user shouldn't be able to select either Date or Month
2. Only after selecting Year, user should be able to select Month and after that, Day.
3. The html element containing these `<select>` tags is loaded dynamically through .load() function. Hence, forced to use $('body').on(....)

Kindly refer this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/jjdJX/299/) to see what I have done.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control year">
        <option>Year</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control month">
        <option>Month</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control day">
        <option>Day</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

var dd_cal, year, month, day, num_year, num_month, num_days, i;

$('body').on('change', '.year', function () {
    year = $(this);
    dd_cal = year.parent();
    month = dd_cal.find($('.month'));
    day = dd_cal.find($('.day'));

    num_year = year.val();

    if (month.children().length <= 1) { //Only if <select> is empty fill it
        month.append('<option value="december">December</option>\n\
                          <option value="november">November</option>\n\
                          <option value="october">October</option>\n\
                          <option value="september">September</option>\n\
                          <option value="august">August</option>\n\
                          <option value="july">July</option>\n\
                          <option value="june">June</option>\n\
                          <option value="may">May</option>\n\
                          <option value="april">April</option>\n\
                          <option value="march">March</option>\n\
                          <option value="february">February</option>\n\
                          <option value="january">January</option>');
    }
    if (num_year == 'Year') { //Remove all Months and Days if default value (i.e."Year") of Year is selected.
        month.add(day).children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();
    }
});

$('body').on('change', month, function () {
    num_month = 13 - month[0].selectedIndex;
    num_days = Math.round(((new Date(num_year, num_month)) - (new Date(num_year, num_month - 1))) / 86400000);

    if (month.val() == 'Month') { //Remove all Days if default value (i.e."Month") of Month is selected.
        day.children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();
    }

    day.children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();

    for (i = num_days; i >= 1; i--) {
        day.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
    }
});

});
```

For the first time when you see the menus, only year has values. Both Month and Days are empty. Then select only **Year** and check the other 2 menus, you will find the following issues:

**Issues**

1. The **Months** are filled properly when a Year is selected, but even **Days** are filled when only Year is selected. This should fill only after any Month is selected.
2. After selecting Month, if the "default" value of Year is selected (i.e. "Year"), both Months and Days should be emptied, but doesn't happen.
3. The `day.children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();` is used to empty the Days filled previously and fill with new values based on the Month selected (for every new selection). But instead of triggering only for change in **Month**, this is triggered even after each time the **Day** is  selected. Try selecting a day from the fiddle and you can see that the value always remains as "Day".

Kindly help me with this by modifying my fiddle. Thank you.

P.S.: I do not want to use any kind of plugin or a calendar to accomplish this since it is a pretty simple and direct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
var dd_cal, year, month, day, num_year, num_month, num_days, i;

            $('body').on('change', '.year', function() {
                year = $('.year');

               if($(this).val() == 'Year')
               {

                 $('.month'). children('option:not(:first)').remove();   
                    $('.day'). children('option:not(:first)').remove(); 
               }
                else
                {
                dd_cal = year.parent();
                month = dd_cal.find($('.month'));
                day = dd_cal.find($('.day'));

                if (month.children().length <= 1) {
                    month.append('<option value="december">December</option>\n\
                              <option value="november">November</option>\n\
                              <option value="october">October</option>\n\
                              <option value="september">September</option>\n\
                              <option value="august">August</option>\n\
                              <option value="july">July</option>\n\
                              <option value="june">June</option>\n\
                              <option value="may">May</option>\n\
                              <option value="april">April</option>\n\
                              <option value="march">March</option>\n\
                              <option value="february">February</option>\n\
                              <option value="january">January</option>');
                }
                }
            });

            $('body').on('change', '.month', function() {
                num_year = year.val();
                num_month = 13 - month[0].selectedIndex;
                num_days = Math.round(((new Date(num_year, num_month)) - (new Date(num_year, num_month - 1))) / 86400000);

                day.children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();

                for (i = num_days; i >= 1; i--) { 
                    day.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
                }
            }); 

});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your quick and accurate response. But I have multiple elements having these `<select>` tags. So, when a Year is selected, only the corresponding Month and Days have to be affected. That's the reason I used `month = dd_cal.find($('.month'));
                day = dd_cal.find($('.day'));`

Comment: multiple elements means having select tags ? you have many year,month,day select tags?

Comment: Yeah, I mean I have multiple sets of them. Like I have Date of Birth, Date of Starting something, Date of Completeing something and so on....... So multiple sets of 'year','month' and 'day'. Checkout this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jjdJX/302/. When you change the year of First Set, only month and day of Set 1 will be affected, whereas the second and third Set remain unaltered

Comment: I just don't understand why the -1 !! I mean what's wrong with this question !! It'd be great if someone could point it out to me